# how we can use web service in to appcelerator titanium

Tags: titanium, appcelerator-mobile

i want to know how to use web services like [SOAP services] in objective services. how to call stub and how to use its methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this https://github.com/kwhinnery/Suds