# Using webservice for android (Titanium) sending paramerters and response in json format?

Tags: android, json, web-services, titanium, appcelerator

Any way of using webservice for android through which we can send paramerters to serveer and receive response in json format?I have tested nusoap for iPhone that is working fine but not for android.Any one help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use Web Services with Android Titanium, you should have a look at the following,

[how we can use web service in to appcelerator titanium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777663/how-we-can-use-web-service-in-to-appcelerator-titanium)

Comment: Actually i tested it in kitchen sink examples.Working for android as well. Now question is can we have our own defined method and parameters in web service instead of currency conversion?I f possible then its all what i want.By the way thanks for your quick response.